# AccessDeniedException: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to make a java program which blocks the facebook page in web browsers. I'm trying to overwrite somehow the hosts file, but the file is disabled to overwriting. I tried to copy him to my desktop, then append a line which blocks the page, and then copy to the etc folder and click to copy (or overwrite) the file. But i can't do it in java, all what i did was create another file in the same folder and append lines to it. But then i can't copy the new file to old, i dont know how to do it, here's my code, i'm waiting for a solutions :)

```
public class Sandbox {

    private final static File zdroj = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
    private final static File ciel = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hostsTemp");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Files.copy(zdroj.toPath(), ciel.toPath());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ciel, true)));
        writer.append("\n\n127.0.0.1 facebook.com www.facebook.com http://www.facebook.com/ http://facebook.com");
        writer.close();
        Files.delete(zdroj.toPath());
        Files.copy(ciel.toPath(), zdroj.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Sandbox.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: I hope you are not the IT guy in my company :)

Comment: You need administrator rights to override this file. Try launching your application as Administrator and It should work. If not, try  removing the "Read only" flag on that file. Or you could allow your current user to modify the file, but it's absolutly not recommended.

Comment: Assuming you get this to work, wouldn't running this program multiple times create duplicate host mappings?

Comment: It's because of software like this that Microsoft added UAC and why other OS's force you into a non-privileged account with special mechanisms to "approve" elevation of privs (like sudo).

Comment: @Brandon -  yes, i forgot to add the line with deleting the temp file.. can anyone help me how to run the application as administrator? thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run your application with elevated permissions. Try starting it with some administrator user.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Can you help me? Do i have to make an .exe application from my java project and start it as administrator? I'm not clear how to do it.

Comment: How do you run it? and IDE or command prompt? either way, you will have to run that program with administrative privileges..